# Does React skip components within render with falsy ternary values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This question might be a bit odd but bear with me.

I have a component called `HomeComponent` which is the first component to get rendered when the app starts. Within this component, I have other smaller components that get rendered depending on the `state` of `HomeComponent`.

I know it is not the most beautiful code but here is a snippet of `HomeComponent render()`.

```
    {
      this.state.isInPinlockMode
      ?
      <PinlockComponent
        onPinCorrect={this.onHidePinlock}
      />
      :

      this.state.isInPastYearsMode
      ?
      <PastYearsComponent
        onClosePastYears={this.onClosePastYears}
      />
      :

      this.state.isInDashboardMode
      ?
      <DashboardComponent
        onCloseDashboardMode={this.onCloseDashboardMode}
      />
      :

      this.state.isInJournalMode
      ?
      <JournalComponent
        onCloseJournalMode={this.onCloseJournalMode}
      />
      :
      ...another component
```

I am using react native RAM modules and inline-requires. This means that when HomeComponent first renders all the above-listed components have not yet been required.
They only get required when a user presses a certain button within `HomeComponent`.

However, I am unsure if these components are still slowing down the `render()` of HomeComponent just by being within its `render()` method.

Are they slowing it down?
Is HomeComponent **skipping** these components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transpile your code (by Babel or something similar), you can see, that

```
<PinlockComponent
        onPinCorrect={this.onHidePinlock}
      />
```

is transpiled to

```
 React.createElement(PinlockComponent, {
  onPinCorrect: onHidePinlock
})
```

which means, it is just a function call (never forget that JSX will be transpiled to JS). If you use that function call inside a ternary  operator, it only gets executed, if the condition returns true.

The same goes for the `&&` abreviation:

```
condition && <PinlockComponent
        onPinCorrect={this.onHidePinlock}
      />;
```

So no, it will not reduce the execution performance.

Comment: Thanks, I was fearing they were slowing down the render method :)

Comment: Nope their not, but you should consider @gazdagergo's approach of using the `&&` operator to enhance readability.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&&` opreator:

```js
const PinlockComponent = () => 'PinlockComponent ';
const PastYearsComponent = () => 'PastYearsComponent ';
const DashboardComponent = () => 'DashboardComponent ';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isInPinlockMode: false,
    isInPastYearsMode: true,
    isInDashboardMode: true
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.isInPinlockMode && <PinlockComponent />}
        {this.state.isInPastYearsMode && <PastYearsComponent />}
        {this.state.isInDashboardMode && <DashboardComponent />}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```